# How to display timing information of proofs in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I have a proof `by eval` that is somewhat slow, and I would like optimize the code. To do so less blindly, it would be great if jEdit could display the time it took to do the `by eval` proof.

Is that possible with Isabelle 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isabelle can be like Perl, where [there's more than one way to do it.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)

From having seen a few suggestions on the [Isabelle user's list](https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/index.html), in jEdit, I turn timing information on and off the same way that I turn commands like `show_types` on and off.

I import a file called `i.thy` like this:

```
theory MFZ
imports Complex_Main "../../../../../../ithy/i"
begin
```

To look at timing information, in `i.thy`, I have a bunch of information commands, one being the command

```
ML_command "Toplevel.timing := false"
```

I set it to true in `i.thy`, and in my working THY I start changing `by` statements to `apply`, and then back to `by` after I've seen the timing information in the output panel.

To turn the timing information off, you have to change the `true` back to `false`. You can't just delete `ML_command "Toplevel.timing := true"`.

If you have a series of `apply` statements as a proof, you can add the timing sums up, or combine them in one `apply/by` statement, to get the timing for a single `apply` statement, like switching the statements

```
apply(simp)
apply(rule)
by(auto)
```

to

```
apply(simp,rule,auto)
```

To edit commands and change `false` to `true`, or vice versa, is probably not much slower than wading through menus to accomplish the same thing.

You could create a jEdit macro to insert the command where you're working, but then you'd have to highlight it and delete it after not needing it any more.

Here's an image of how I keep two views open. The right view shows where I've set `Toplevel.timing` to true, and the left window shows where I've changed a `by` to an `apply`. The [image size is 1211x488](http://gc44.github.io/viz/img_1300/130502a__toplevel_timing.png), and it looks good in Chrome on my end.

http://gc44.github.io/viz/img_1300/130502a__toplevel_timing.png

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, although `ML_command "Toplevel.timing := true"` is all I was looking for :-)

Comment: @Joachim, yea, I suppose you don't need newbie style advice, but I can spend a lot of time trying to find a practical way to work in an IDE, like trying to get fancy with macros and then deciding it's just easier to import and edit a THY with a big long list of information commands, so maybe others knowing "my system" might save them some time. I also wanted to see what combination of markdown and HTML it takes to use an image on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Sure, others will likely benefit from the detailed answer.